# How to prevent my app from being closed by user in/from Recent

Tags: android, facebook, whatsapp, android-recents, oppo

In Phones Like Oppo and One Plus 6 some apps like Facebook and Whatsbook do not get closed from recent.

When I close all apps from recent, these 2 apps Facebook and Whatsapp remains there.

In the screenshot I have attached, we can see a lock at top right corner of facebook and whatsapp icons, but no lock on Videos Icon.

**Android Version :** 8.1 and above

**My question is:** How can I do that by code. How to prevent my app from being closed by user in/from Recent

[image: screenshot]

Comment: THis is not a feature of Android.  You can close facebook from recents, I just did it.  If this was possible every app would have it on.

Comment: Dear 
I have checked properly in Oppo and One Plus 6 I have, and then I posted this question.
You can see the lock on icons of FB abd Wahtsapp but not on Videos app.

Comment: That's a feature of their launcher app, and it isn't a feature of ANdroid in general.  It may be that there's an SDK to do it, but it won't work in general and it may be using a whitelist.

Comment: Thanks
So any hint how can I do this ? Pls

Answer (score 4):

You can't add this feature.

But if you wants prevent app kill from recent don't show in recent list

try **excludeFromRecents** (hack)

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

**excludeFromRecents:** Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen.

Comment: How about hide it from `Active applications` in `RAM Management` bro?

Comment: @Chivorn thats not possible